# Inserting Text above image

Tags: html, css

-i set the background on black
-i set an image and changed the opacity so that it will blend in with the background.
-tried to create a text above the image but it wont show.

Here is a preview of the website:

[image: preview]

and the following are the code that i did :)

/* Unfortunately the "---Greetings" text cant be seen in the preview and i tried finding it by changing colors just in case it was just misplaced but it didnt.

I tested another picture without the opacity, it worked but when i tried lessening it it disappears again :( */

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 430px;
  left: 670px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 101%;
  min-height: 50%;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: relative;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: red;
}

.mid-left h1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  top: 10px;
}

.navbar {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: black;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: "montserrat-extrabold", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.navbar li {
  float: left;
}

.navbar li+li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}


/*changing of color when hover*/

.navbar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: red;
  transition: 0.6s;
}


/*add color to the selective link*/

.navbar a:active {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> R E S U M E</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <!--   <div id="bg">
   <img src="Cover1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
 -->

  <div class="container">
    <img src="Cover1.jpg" alt="Me">
    <div class="mid-left">
      <h1>----- Greetings!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <header class="flex flex-vertical-center">

    <div class="navbar flex flex-horizontal-center">
      <ul>
        <li class="navitem"> <a href="home.html" class="active"> Home </a> </li>
        <li class="navitem"> <a href="personal.html">Personal</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"> <a href="education.html">Education</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"> <a href="experience.html">Experience</a></li>
        s
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @AlonEitan it just moves the navbar/menu up the page

Comment: Yes, I saw and deleted it (I misread the question). Why did you set `left: -50%;` to `.container`?

Comment: @AlonEitan i actually copied that code from an article and simply adjusted the "left:  and right:" to adjust the picture :)

Comment: So I think that is the main issue, it takes the element out of the visible part of the screen. So I think removing it and working with the z-index will make the text to be visible, but I also suspect that it will affect other things. Do you have this page available online so I can inspect the elements?

Comment: @AlonEitan i have a link on my gdrive so you could test it :)  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SSJzejRuvd4wNUeUu11W41lfgMXJ5kY3

Comment: I'm glad to see that you got your answer. Well done  Valerio

Comment: thank you too for helping! @AlonEitan :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see `.mid-left` because

```
.container {
  ...
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
}
```

You have to remove top and left with these value. Furthermore I suggest to you to use `background-image: url('Cover1.jpg')` on `.container` and remove `<img src="Cover.jpg" alt="Me">`

Comment: w3schools state that `zIndex` works on _positioned elements_ that are absolute, relative and fixed, but it also works for `position:sticky` elements as well (So I don't trust their documentation at all)

Comment: i tried using the z-index as you said by putting (-1) on the img and a (+1) on the h1. it didnt appear :(

Comment: Thank you so  much! @ValerioGiocondi i see my error!

Comment: oh yeah! i tried the suggestion you did. it just made the image disappear when i removed it from the html and applied it in .container :( @AldoMariaLandini

Comment: the problem was "-50%" on top and left attribute of .container. Could you use http://jsfiddle.net/ in order to pass to me your code and fix it?

Comment: wait a minute, I've created a JSfiddle, and I'm working on it

Comment: I got it! When you put your image on background-image, it's not disappeared, but your .container's heigth is pratically 0px (even in CSS is 100%). I don't know why, but I put heigth: 200px as example.
http://jsfiddle.net/e537vcLq/